# How can I undo adding a new file to git?

Tags: git

I did `git status` and saw a bunch of new files, e.g.:

Changes to be committed:
      (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
    new file:   project/swiftFile1.swift
    new file:   projec/swiftFile2.swift

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    modified:   project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

    Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
```

I did `git add -A` and it added to git all the files above, now I see there:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    modified:   project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
    new file:   project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
    modified:   project/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
    modified:   project/swiftFile1.swift
    modified:   project/swiftFile2.swift
```

And then I realized I don't want to `push` to the repo this file:

```
project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
```

so before I do `git push` what could I do to stop committing this particular file (but not remove it from my hard drive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer in your question:

```
Changes to be committed: (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
```

To unstage the file, type:

```
git reset HEAD project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/M.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
```

I might add that this does not undo the changes you made to the file.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer as soon as stack let me, in couple minutes ;)